# code in wordpress PHP

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I have in my DB two different table wp_users,arduino contract each of them has ID as an attribute
In wordpress I wrote this code to connect between those table but is show nothing
Where is the wrong ? 
thank you

```
 <?php
global $wpdb;
$arduino_contract = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, current_amount   FROM  wp_users ,arduino_contract WHERE ID.wp_user= C_ID.arduino_contract ;");
//print_r($arduino_contract  ); // to display the content
foreach($arduino_contract as $hg){
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$hg->current_amount."</td>";
echo "<td>".$hg->ID."</td>";

echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Are you correctly joining the tables? You can always try to execute the query against the database directly to see if it returns the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

does shows any error?
and i think you should write your query like this

```
$arduino_contract = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, current_amount   FROM  wp_users ,arduino_contract WHERE wp_users.ID= arduino_contract.C_ID");
```

Comment: Can you tell me what error is it? It seems you had written wrong table name. It should be `wp_users.ID` instead of `wp_user`.

Comment: Thank you very much Milan it was too small change ^-^